# how should i parse netstat command?

Tags: netstat

I only want mysql and status of 3306.

I try these things but couldnt get output which i want.

[image]

When I try `netstat -anob | findstr 3306` information of mysql is not displayed.

When I try `netstat -anob | findstr sql` information of port status is not displayed.
as in snap shot you can see.

I want whole information of process and port listening.

I try `netstat -anob` it gives all the information. It means my parsing with finsdstr is wrong, please guide me in this.

Comment: What's the exact output of `netstat -anob`? (Could "`FIND: Parameter format not correct`" be a clue?)

Comment: A batch script was created to parse netstat: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26839729/1569434. Is that what you're looking for?