# How to fetch output of command of powershell with C++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, powershell, cmd, console

i implemented program of network statistics with help of powershell [scrpit](http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71). the program is running successfully and giving me perfact output as well . below is my program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
       string strPath = "C:\\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1";
      char str[50] =  "C:\\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1";

       char command[500];

//access function:
       //The function returns 0 if the file has the given mode.
       //The function returns –1 if the named file does not exist or does not have the given mode
       if(access(strPath.c_str(),0) == 0)
       {


_snprintf(command, sizeof(command), "Start Powershell.exe -noexit Set -executionpolicy;.'%s';Get-NetworkStatistics",str);
system(command);



       }

       else 
       {
              system("cls");
              cout << "File is not exist";
              system("pause");
        }
return 0;
}
```

! [here is the output of above program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNPdo.png)

as you can see the output is in the powershell windows.. i want to fetch all this data of powershell output and want to display it in console. how should it possible?

please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Unless you need to do display the info in realtime as it becomes available, just redirect it to a file, then read that file from C++.

Since `netstat` was lobotomized in Windows XP SP 2 or thereabouts I can understand using Powershell.

But it *may* just be that `netstat` will serve your needs, and then you don't have to deal with any of that complication.

---

By the way, I recommend using a scripting language for scripting tasks. There is of course the complication that Powershell scripting is disabled by default, otherwise using the Powershell scripting facility would be indicated. But e.g. in this case a [cmd.exe] batch file would be more natural than doing its job from C++.

The Windows Script Host shell objects, available from JScript and VBScript, provide functionality for process execution with output grabbing.

There is a little snag in that you then have to *poll* the output, but I think it's still easier than doing this at the C/C++ API level.

Comment: thanx for reply the problem with netstat i find is that itcant get process name in first command, for getting process name first have to run command netstat -ano and than according to PID  write another command tasklist /svc/fi "2010, i find it much complex when specially when you want both port and process name in once.

Comment: well `netstat -a -b -n -o` in elevated command line appears to display the executables.

Comment: it has some issue 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24114662/how-should-i-parse-netstat-command?noredirect=1#comment37202862_24114662

Comment: try giving it the options *separately*, each option prefixed with hyphen.

Comment: it works but main problem is that when you want to all information with specific process name or port it will not work, when i try netstat -a -b -n -o | findstr mysql it only give process name mysql not name of port and address and PID is not rertrieve..:(

Comment: to use `findstr` you would first have to join line pairs. try to process the output in C++ or a script. hm, i think i would use script. ;-)