# How to run internal Powershell script function from cmd.exe with arguments

Tags: windows, powershell, command-prompt, netstat, windows-scripting

I want to use a powershell (.ps1) script in the command prompt without using this commands

```
   Powershell.exe -noexit Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -file "C:\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1"
```

Currently this command opens powershell windows. I want direct cmd to use this script and giving me output. Is it possible?

Below is my Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1 script. please guide me is there any way to use it directly?

```
function Get-NetworkStatistics {
<#
.SYNOPSIS
    Display current TCP/IP connections for local or remote system

.FUNCTIONALITY
    Computers

.DESCRIPTION
    Display current TCP/IP connections for local or remote system.  Includes the process ID (PID) and process name for each connection.
    If the port is not yet established, the port number is shown as an asterisk (*).    

.PARAMETER ProcessName
    Gets connections by the name of the process. The default value is '*'.

.PARAMETER Port
    The port number of the local computer or remote computer. The default value is '*'.

.PARAMETER Address
    Gets connections by the IP address of the connection, local or remote. Wildcard is supported. The default value is '*'.

.PARAMETER Protocol
    The name of the protocol (TCP or UDP). The default value is '*' (all)

.PARAMETER State
    Indicates the state of a TCP connection. The possible states are as follows:

    Closed      - The TCP connection is closed. 
    Close_Wait  - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for a connection termination request from the local user. 
    Closing     - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for an acknowledgement of the connection termination request sent previously. 
    Delete_Tcb  - The transmission control buffer (TCB) for the TCP connection is being deleted. 
    Established     - The TCP handshake is complete. The connection has been established and data can be sent. 
    Fin_Wait_1  - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for a connection termination request from the remote endpoint or for an acknowledgement of the connection termination request sent previously. 
    Fin_Wait_2  - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for a connection termination request from the remote endpoint. 
    Last_Ack    - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for the final acknowledgement of the connection termination request sent previously. 
    Listen      - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is listening for a connection request from any remote endpoint. 
    Syn_Received    - The local endpoint of the TCP connection has sent and received a connection request and is waiting for an acknowledgment. 
    Syn_Sent    - The local endpoint of the TCP connection has sent the remote endpoint a segment header with the synchronize (SYN) control bit set and is waiting for a matching connection request. 
    Time_Wait   - The local endpoint of the TCP connection is waiting for enough time to pass to ensure that the remote endpoint received the acknowledgement of its connection termination request. 
    Unknown     - The TCP connection state is unknown.

    Values are based on the TcpState Enumeration:
    http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpstate%28VS.85%29.aspx

    Cookie Monster - modified these to match netstat output per here:
    http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137984

.PARAMETER ComputerName
    If defined, run this command on a remote system via WMI.  \\computername\c$\netstat.txt is created on that system and the results returned here

.PARAMETER ShowHostNames
    If specified, will attempt to resolve local and remote addresses.

.PARAMETER tempFile
    Temporary file to store results on remote system.  Must be relative to remote system (not a file share).  Default is "C:\netstat.txt"

.EXAMPLE
    Get-NetworkStatistics | Format-Table

.EXAMPLE
    Get-NetworkStatistics iexplore -computername k-it-thin-02 -ShowHostNames | Format-Table

.EXAMPLE
    Get-NetworkStatistics -ProcessName md* -Protocol tcp

.EXAMPLE
    Get-NetworkStatistics -Address 192* -State LISTENING

.EXAMPLE
    Get-NetworkStatistics -State LISTENING -Protocol tcp

.OUTPUTS
    System.Management.Automation.PSObject

.NOTES
    Author: Shay Levy, code butchered by Cookie Monster
    Shay's Blog: http://PowerShay.com
    Cookie Monster's Blog: http://ramblingcookiemonster.wordpress.com

.LINK
    http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-NetworkStatistics-66057d71
#>  
[OutputType('System.Management.Automation.PSObject')]
[CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName='name')]

param(

    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ParameterSetName='name')]
    [System.String]$ProcessName='*',

    [Parameter(Position=0, ValueFromPipeline=$true,ParameterSetName='address')]
    [System.String]$Address='*',        

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true,ParameterSetName='port')]
    $Port='*',

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('*','tcp','udp')]
    [System.String]$Protocol='*',

    [Parameter()]
    [ValidateSet('*','Closed','Close_Wait','Closing','Delete_Tcb','DeleteTcb','Established','Fin_Wait_1','Fin_Wait_2','Last_Ack','Listening','Syn_Received','Syn_Sent','Time_Wait','Unknown')]
    [System.String]$State='*',

    [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true, ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
    [validatescript({test-connection -count 2 -buffersize 16 -quiet -ComputerName $_})]
    [System.String]$computername=$env:COMPUTERNAME,

    [switch]$ShowHostnames,

    [switch]$ShowProcessNames = $true,  

    [System.String]$tempFile = "C:\netstat.txt"

)

begin{
    #Define properties
        $properties = 'Protocol','LocalAddress','LocalPort','RemoteAddress','RemotePort','State','ProcessName','PID'

    #Collect processes
        if($ShowProcessNames){
            Try {
                $processes = get-process -computername $computername -ErrorAction stop | select name, id
            }
            Catch {
                Write-warning "Could not run Get-Process -computername $computername.  Verify permissions and connectivity.  Defaulting to no ShowProcessNames"
                $ShowProcessNames = $false
            }
        }

    #store hostnames in array for quick lookup
        $dnsCache = @()

}

process{

    #Handle remote systems
        if($computername -ne $env:COMPUTERNAME){

            #define command
                [string]$cmd = "cmd /c c:\windows\system32\netstat.exe -ano >> $tempFile"

            #define remote file path - computername, drive, folder path
                $remoteTempFile = "\\{0}\{1}`${2}" -f "$computername", (split-path $tempFile -qualifier).TrimEnd(":"), (Split-Path $tempFile -noqualifier)

            #delete previous results
                Try{
                    $null = Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList "cmd /c del $tempFile" -ComputerName $computername -ErrorAction stop
                }
                Catch{
                    Write-Warning "Could not invoke create win32_process on $computername to delete $tempfile"
                }

            #run command
                Try{
                    $processID = (Invoke-WmiMethod -class Win32_process -name Create -ArgumentList $cmd -ComputerName $computername -ErrorAction stop).processid
                }
                Catch{
                    #If we didn't run netstat, break everything off
                    Throw $_
                    Break
                }

            #wait for process to complete
                while (
                    #This while should return true until the process completes
                        $(
                            try{
                                get-process -id $processid -computername $computername -ErrorAction Stop
                            }
                            catch{
                                $FALSE
                            }
                        )
                ) {
                    start-sleep -seconds 2 
                }

            #gather results
                if(test-path $remoteTempFile){

                    Try {
                        $results = Get-Content $remoteTempFile | Select-String -Pattern '\s+(TCP|UDP)'
                    }
                    Catch {
                        Throw "Could not get content from $remoteTempFile for results"
                        Break
                    }

                    Remove-Item $remoteTempFile -force

                }
                else{
                    Throw "'$tempFile' on $computername converted to '$remoteTempFile'.  This path is not accessible from your system."
                    Break
                }
        }
        else{
            #gather results on local PC
                $results = netstat -ano | Select-String -Pattern '\s+(TCP|UDP)'
        }

    #initialize counter for progress
        $totalCount = $results.count
        $count = 0

    #Loop through each line of results    
        foreach($result in $results) {

            $item = $result.line.split(' ',[System.StringSplitOptions]::RemoveEmptyEntries)

            if($item[1] -notmatch '^\[::'){

                #parse the netstat line for local address and port
                    if (($la = $item[1] -as [ipaddress]).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetworkV6'){
                        $localAddress = $la.IPAddressToString
                        $localPort = $item[1].split('\]:')[-1]
                    }
                    else {
                        $localAddress = $item[1].split(':')[0]
                        $localPort = $item[1].split(':')[-1]
                    } 

                #parse the netstat line for remote address and port
                    if (($ra = $item[2] -as [ipaddress]).AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetworkV6'){
                        $remoteAddress = $ra.IPAddressToString
                        $remotePort = $item[2].split('\]:')[-1]
                    }
                    else {
                        $remoteAddress = $item[2].split(':')[0]
                        $remotePort = $item[2].split(':')[-1]
                    } 

                #parse the netstat line for other properties
                    $procId = $item[-1]
                    $proto = $item[0]
                    $status = if($item[0] -eq 'tcp') {$item[3]} else {$null}    

                #Display progress bar prior to getting process name or host name
                    Write-Progress  -Activity "Resolving host and process names"`
                        -Status "Resolving process ID $procId with remote address $remoteAddress and local address $localAddress"`
                        -PercentComplete (( $count / $totalCount ) * 100)

                #If we are running showprocessnames, get the matching name
                    if($ShowProcessNames){

                        #handle case where process spun up in the time between running get-process and running netstat
                        if($procName = $processes | ?{$_.id -eq $procId} | select -ExpandProperty name ){ }
                        else {$procName = "Unknown"}

                    }
                    else{$procName = "NA"}

                #if the showhostnames switch is specified, try to map IP to hostname
                    if($showHostnames){
                        $tmpAddress = $null
                        try{
                            if($remoteAddress -eq "127.0.0.1" -or $remoteAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"){
                                $remoteAddress = $computername
                            }
                            elseif($remoteAddress -match "\w"){

                                #check with dns cache first
                                    if($tmpAddress = $dnsCache -match "`t$remoteAddress$"){
                                        $remoteAddress = ( $tmpAddress -split "`t" )[0]
                                        write-verbose "using cached REMOTE '$tmpADDRESS'"
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        #if address isn't in the cache, resolve it and add it
                                            $tmpAddress = $remoteAddress
                                            $remoteAddress = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress("$remoteAddress").hostname
                                            $dnsCache += "$remoteAddress`t$tmpAddress"
                                            write-verbose "using non cached REMOTE '$remoteAddress`t$tmpAddress"
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        catch{ }

                        try{

                            if($localAddress -eq "127.0.0.1" -or $localAddress -eq "0.0.0.0"){
                                $localAddress = $computername
                            }
                            elseif($localAddress -match "\w"){
                                #check with dns cache first
                                    if($tmpAddress = $dnsCache -match "`t$localAddress$"){
                                        $localAddress = ( $tmpAddress -split "`t" )[0]
                                        write-verbose "using cached LOCAL '$tmpADDRESS'"
                                    }
                                    else{
                                        #if address isn't in the cache, resolve it and add it
                                            $tmpAddress = $localAddress
                                            $localAddress = [System.Net.DNS]::GetHostByAddress("$localAddress").hostname
                                            $dnsCache += "$localAddress`t$tmpAddress"
                                            write-verbose "using non cached LOCAL '$localAddress'`t'$tmpAddress'"
                                    }
                            }
                        }
                        catch{ }
                    }

                #Define the object  
                    $pso = New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property @{
                        PID = $procId
                        ProcessName = $procName
                        Protocol = $proto
                        LocalAddress = $localAddress
                        LocalPort = $localPort
                        RemoteAddress =$remoteAddress
                        RemotePort = $remotePort
                        State = $status
                    } | Select-Object -Property $properties                             

                #Filter and display the object
                    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'port'){
                        if($pso.RemotePort -like $Port -or $pso.LocalPort -like $Port){
                            if($pso.Protocol -like $Protocol -and $pso.State -like $State){
                                $pso
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'address'){
                        if($pso.RemoteAddress -like $Address -or $pso.LocalAddress -like $Address){
                            if($pso.Protocol -like $Protocol -and $pso.State -like $State){
                                $pso
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if($PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName -eq 'name'){      
                        if($pso.ProcessName -like $ProcessName){
                            if($pso.Protocol -like $Protocol -and $pso.State -like $State){
                                $pso
                            }
                        }
                    }

                #Increment the progress counter
                    $count++
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Well.. I want an orange juice but whithout oranges is it possible ??

Comment: after second read maybe you just want to run this from cmd : `powershell.exe -noprofile -file c:\path\to\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1`

Comment: hi thanx for help i try it before as i mention it in my question..

my main purpose it to run this function Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbi1 | Format-Table -autosize ..how it will possible with cmd

Comment: this id not what you've tried before, this should not open an external powershell window...

Comment: actully i am implementing this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24180653/how-to-fetch-output-of-command-of-powershell-with-c/24180738?noredirect=1#comment37326046_24180738

Answer (score 3):

Dito to what @Kayasax said so picturesquely - you *cannot* run a powershell script without powershell, period. An alternative to your command is the following, executes and exits:

```
@powershell C:\Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1
```

Comment: hi thanx for help i try it before as i mention it in my question.. my main purpose it to run this function Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbi1 | Format-Table -autosize ..how it will possible with cmd

Comment: @Raf, you're not understanding. PowerShell scripts must be executed by a PowerShell host application. `cmd.exe` **is not** a PowerShell host. `powershell.exe` is. The only way to avoid using `powershell.exe` is to create your own host which behaves the way you want it to - but you still won't be using `cmd.exe` then.

Answer (score 1):

In response to your comment, "...my main purpose it to run this function `Get-NetworkStatistics -computername Gbi1 | Format-Table -autosize`..."

You can add these two lines to the end of `Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1`
(This is a hack to get your purpose met, negates most of the power of Shay's script):

```
$ARG_COMPNAME = $args[0]
Get-NetworkStatistics -computername $ARG_COMPNAME | Format-Table -autosize
```

Then you call the Powershell script along the lines of:

```
C:\>powershell.exe -noprofile -file Get-NetworkStatistics.ps1 Gbi1
```

The script runs and dumps a netstat table to screen and dumps a file c:\netstat.txt